# Is it possible to manually edit the alt tag for a picture post on Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

Tumblr lets you edit the HTML of your theme but not individual pages. There is no default option to edit the alt tag of a picture that you post; Tumblr automatically assigns the text associated with the picture as the alt tag.

As far as I know, editing the alt tag is not possible however I was hoping someone might have an answer here.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no - Tumblr doesn't let you edit the alt text of your photos.

The longer answer is that it should be possible if you tell Tumblr in [Settings](http://www.tumblr.com/preferences) that you want to edit your posts using plain text/HTML. Then, create a new *text* post, and add the photo with a normal `<img>` tag and with whatever `alt` text you like. This should work, although users reading your blog from their dashboards instead of your homepage will have to click through to see the image at all.

An issue here is that you cannot upload an image to Tumblr using this method - you have to link to an image with the `img` tag, so it must be hosted elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

My way of doing this... and it is a really annoying way is:

1. edit post in Rich Text mode
2. upload the images you want in the post with the inline image uploader
3. turn it in to HTML edit mode and add alt text to images
4. save the post while you are in HTML edit mode

So this way tumblr hosts my images AND I can use my own alt text.

For example [in this post](http://yzahk.in/post/122868246965/recettear-an-item-shops-tale-kritika) I gave up on this after the first image. It would be much more convenient if they would give us an input for alt text. But alt text is too technical for most users I think and now days Tumblr is all about fast inline editing and simplicity for all.